# How does C ^ (dash) exponent operator work?

Tags: c, calc

I'm pretty new to programming and I just can't find the reason why my output differs from desired one. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

float fallingDistance (int t);
int main () {
    int t;
    float result=0.0;
    printf("t <seconds>\td <meters>\n");
    for(t=1;t<=10;t++) {
        result = fallingDistance (t);
        printf("\t%d\t%.2f\n",t,result);
    }
}

float fallingDistance (int t) {
    const float Grav = 9.8;
    float fallD = 0.5*Grav*(t^2);
    return fallD;
}
```

#### My input is:

`t=1`

#### Desired output:

`0.5*9.8*(1^2) = 4.90`

#### Actual output:

`0.5*9.8*(3) = 14.70`

Now if t=1, `fallD` should be 0.5*9.8*(1^2) = 4.90 but the output is 14.70. Any idea why?

Comment: `^` is XOR, not exponentiation

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C, there is no `^` operator for expotentation. Use `Grav(t*t)`. There is no syntax error though, because `^` is bitwise XOR operator. It takes two numbers and perform XOR on their corresponding bits.

for example, when `t=6` `t^2` will be:

```
6:   110
2:   010
6^2: 100 which in dec is 4.
```

You can also use `pow` function from `Math` library. Some introduction can be found on [tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_pow.htm).

Bitwise XOR works in the following way: it takes all bits of two numbers and compares bits on the same positions (counting from the end). The difference is marked with 1 and no difference (equality) is marked with 0.

Definition:

```
a   b  a^b
-----------
0   0   0
0   1   1
1   0   1
1   1   0
```

Example:

```
10 ^ 4 = 1010_2 ^ 100_2 = 1110_2 = 14  //_2 stands for binary
```

because:

```
 1010
^ 100
-----
=1110
```